# How to parse soap client response in php

Tags: xml, soap

I have got following response from API.I am trying to parse it but not got any success. I have tried different way but unable to do it. Please help me on this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<CheckPriceBulkResponse xmlns="http://eKeystone.com">
<CheckPriceBulkResult>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="CheckPriceBulk">
<xs:complexType><xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Vendor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
<xs:element name="PartNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
<xs:element name="CustomerPrice" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
<xs:element name="Currency" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<CheckPriceBulk diffgr:id="CheckPriceBulk1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
<Vendor>A13</Vendor>
<PartNumber>10980
</PartNumber>
<CustomerPrice>93.94</CustomerPrice>
<Currency>usd</Currency>
</CheckPriceBulk>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</CheckPriceBulkResult>
</CheckPriceBulkResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Stack overflow is not your personal coding community, please provide your code and describe what is wrong with it in order to get help.

Comment: Please help me to read data like PartNumber, CustomerPrice from this xml response.

Comment: Can you use xpath?

Comment: I can use xpath to read data.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really clarified your question, but if I understand you correctly, the following xpath expressions

```
//PartNumber/text()
```

and

```
  //CustomerPrice/text()
```

should output
`10980`  and `93.94`, respectively.